# Pregenerate INSERT / UPDATE views in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

We're experiencing an issue with Entity Framework where the first time we execute SaveChanges on a very simple object insertion, there is a delay of 2-4 seconds.  I have narrowed this down (via ANTS Performance Profiler) to View Generation.  I've seen and followed the articles for pre-generating views with [EdmGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx) or a [T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx), but this doesn't help: the .Views.cs file only contains SELECT statements, not UPDATE or INSERT statements.  There's been a lot of discussion around EF and performance using precompiled queries, cached queries, etc but it all centers around selects, not inserts or updates which are all hidden behind SaveChanges().

The only way I've found to get EF to generate the INSERT view is to try to insert a row at service startup that I know will fail, such as setting a foreign key to an ID that should never exist.  This seems absolutely ridiculous to me.  Is there a better way?  I don't really care if it happens at compile time or at service startup, but is there a way to force EF to generate all the (basic) UPDATE and INSERT views?  Making the first user of the service wait 2-4 seconds to insert a single row is not acceptable.

We're using EF 4 right now but we will make the jump to EF 5 and .NET 4.5 if necessary to solve this issue.

Edit:
Further investigation has shown that while there *is* overhead the first time SaveChanges() is called on a table while it creates / compiles the update view, it is negligible (30-40ms).  Profiling it makes it look worse than it is due to the huge call stack.  My original timings of 2-4 seconds ended up breaking down into other overhead like:
Creating the first context: 1600ms
First EF operation (which loads or creates query views) 400ms if precompiled, 3000+ms otherwise
Initial connection to the remote database: 500ms

Answer (score 0):

Further digging revealed the time to generate update views is negligible compared to other overhead and doesn't warrant any special handling.